# Using date parameters in a FoxPro query through Microsoft Query/Excel

Tags: excel, foxpro, ms-query

I've got a external data source setup in Microsoft Excel which queries an external FoxPro database via Microsoft Query.

One of the lines in the query is `WHERE (ihead.ih_date>={d '2018-10-01'})` but I want to change this date to be a parameter driven by a cell in Excel.

I've tried all different combinations of where to put the `?` and what to put in the cell, but they all return "Operator/operand type mismatch".

Where should I position the `?` and what should be in the cell?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably because the cell value is being taken as text, try changing ihead.ih_date to dtoc(ihead.ih_date)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Alan I've got it working.

I looked up [what DTOC does](https://www.visualfoxpro.com/dtoc.html), and found I needed to add `,1` to make it indexable.

I also needed to change the excel cell to be formatted as `YYYYMMDD`.

Now it's `(dtoc(ihead.ih_date,1)>=?)` and it works fine.